# Promisify to not return callback array

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there any way that I can augment the callback to only return the `result` and not an array with `raw` in it as well?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var osascript = require('node-osascript');

function osxBackgroundGet(callback) {
  return osascript.execute([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n"), callback);
}

/*
osxBackgroundGet(function(err, result, raw){
  console.log(result);
})
*/

var osxBackgroundGet = Promise.promisify(osxBackgroundGet);

osxBackgroundGet().then(function(signature){
  var result = signature[0];
})
```

Or should I just handle this within the `osxBackgroundGet` `callback`?

Like this:

```
function osxBackgroundGet(callback) {
  return osascript.execute([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n"), function(err, result, raw){
    if(err) return callback(err)
    return callback(err, result)
  });
}
```

I really don't like editing a library's native `callback`. Should I just leave the `signature` array?

I could cut a ton of steps here If I just `promisifyAll` of `osascript`. But I'm still left with that darn `signature array`.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var osascript = Promise.promisifyAll(require('node-osascript'))

osascript.executeAsync([
  'tell application "System Events"',
  'tell current desktop',
  'get picture',
  'end tell',
  'end tell'
].join("\n")).then(function(signature){
  console.log(signature);
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

There's 4 ways I can write / use these functions and I'm confused as to which is the "standard" or I guess the subjective "best" some offer more versatility, and some are easier to understand and work as you'd expect.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var osascript = require('node-osascript');
var osascriptPromise = Promise.promisifyAll(osascript)
```

**OPTION 1**

Returns callback and just returns the entire native callback.

```
function osxBackgroundGetCallback(callback){
  return osascript.execute([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n"), callback);
}

// usage
/*
var getBg = Promise.promisify(osxBackgroundGetCallback);
getBg().then(function(sig){
  var bg = sig[0]
});
*/
```

**OPTION 2**

Returns callback and opens the callback up to return specific value.

```
function osxBackgroundGetCallbackValue(callback){
  return osascript.execute([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n"), function(err, result, raw){
    if(err) return callback(err);
    return callback(result);
  });
}

// usage
/*
var getBg = Promise.promisify(osxBackgroundGetCallbackValue);
getBg().then(function(bg){

});
*/
```

**OPTION 3**

Returns promise with native callback signature array (without the error).

```
function osxBackgroundGetPromise(){
  return osascriptPromise.executeAsync([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n"))
}

// usage
/*
getBg().then(function(sig){
  var bg = sig[0];
});
*/
```

**OPTION 4**

Returns promise with then returning the specific value desired.

```
function osxBackgroundGetPromiseValue(){
  return osascriptPromise.executeAsync([
    'tell application "System Events"',
    'tell current desktop',
    'get picture',
    'end tell',
    'end tell'
  ].join("\n")).then(function(sig){
    var result = sig[0]
    var raw = sig[1]
    return result
  })
}

// usage
/*
getBg().then(function(bg){

});
*/
```

Comment: Why is it a problem if there's a third argument on the callback that you don't care to use?  Just ignore it.  Just because it's there doesn't mean you have to do anything with it.

Comment: Hey @jfriend00 I put an update with four different options for how a function could be written using an existing library and bluebird promisify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is option 1 / 3 but instead of using `then` using [`spread`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise). That way you have access to all of the variables without digging into ambitious arrays.